# Mouse stops functioning after taking couple amount of inputs

Tags: java, android, sockets

Client Code

```
new Thread()
        {

            public void run()
            {

                mousePad.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if(isConnected && out!=null){
                            switch(event.getAction()){
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    //save X and Y positions when user touches the TextView
                                    initX =event.getX();
                                    initY =event.getY();
                                    mouseMoved=false;
                                    break;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                    disX = event.getX()- initX; //Mouse movement in x direction
                                    disY = event.getY()- initY; //Mouse movement in y direction
                            /*set init to new position so that continuous mouse movement
                            is captured*/
                                    initX = event.getX();
                                    initY = event.getY();
                                    if(disX !=0|| disY !=0){
                                        try
                                        {

                                            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                                            bw.write(disX +","+ disY); // to write contents to output stream
                                            l.makeConnection(v);
                                            bw.newLine();
                                            bw.flush();

                                        }
                                        catch (IOException e)
                                        {
                                            Log.i(DebuggString,e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                        out.println(disX +","+ disY); //send mouse movement to server
                                    }
                                    mouseMoved=true;
                                    break;

                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
```

here is server code

```
else if(data.contains(","))
                                                {
                                                       float movex=Float.parseFloat(data.split(",")[0]);//extract movement in x direction
                                                        float movey=Float.parseFloat(data.split(",")[1]);//extract movement in y direction
                                                        Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); //Get current mouse position
                                                        float nowx=point.x;
                                                        float nowy=point.y;

                                                        robot.mouseMove((int)(nowx+movex),(int)(nowy+movey));//Move mouse pointer to new location
                                                        movex = 0;
                                                        movey = 0;
                                                        nowx = 0;
                                                        nowy = 0;

                                                }
```

There is no error no logcat or anything that comes but the server gets jam and does not takes any further commands. please help me out its my final year project.

its has a tonnes and tonnes of cordinates.. when i try to go with the loop the innitial points get blocked and cursor doesnt moves from that position at all.. dont know what to do

Comment: Why would you create a new thread that just sets a touch listener?  That doesn't cause the touch listener to run on that thread-  the touch listener always runs on the UI thread.  I don't think you actually understand what you're doing there.

Comment: Again after some inputs i got a nullpointer exception
'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at testing.Testing.main(Testing.java:120)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1'